# Best way for handling large quantity of different custom automatic emails

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, hyva

**Using:**

- Magento version 2.4.6
- Hyva theme version 1.2.3

**Issue:**
What would be best practice for setting up a large quantity of different automatic email responses?

**Background:**
For a webshop selling hundreds of different technical products, I need to send an automatic e-mail, with installation instructions for the ordered product.
Because each product has different installation instructions I would need to be able to set-up thousands of different rules to automatically trigger the correct automatic email reponse.

**Possible solution:**
"Follow up mail" extension from Amasty seems promising.

Are there any other good alternatives or better ways to set this up?